# Upload file from flash to server PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm going to upload files from flash to server. When user begin, input his *username*, then I send it to php, this way:

```
    var myusername:String = username.text;
    username.restrict = "A-Za-z0-9";
    login_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,login);
    function login (evt:MouseEvent):void{

    var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain/uploads/upload.php");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var userid:String = myusername;
    variables.ID = userid;
    request.data = variables;
    loader.load(request);
}
```

upload.php :

```
<?php
$myuser = $_POST['ID'];
$uploads_dir = './uploads/'.$myuser;

if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],
         $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();
?>
```

The problem is that files upload to *uploads* folder not in user folder. Anyone could help me please?

Comment: check that `$_POST['ID']` actually contains a value otherwise `$uploads_dir` is just going to be the upload dir

Comment: try var_dump($myuser);

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `$_POST['ID']`?

I don't see you setting that anywhere in the request.  There's this:

```
variables.UID = userid;
```

But wouldn't that be `$_POST['UID']` and not `$_POST['ID']`?

Comment: Here : var myusername:String = username.text;

Comment: @Amir: But how does that become a value called `ID` in the request?

Comment: Sorry, but this mistake is only here not in my original code. I corrected this.

Comment: @Amir: Not to sound unhelpful, but what other mistakes are in this code that aren't in the original?  More to the point, when you debug this what is actually in the POST request?